# Qual a diferença de SOME, IN e ANY?

Tags: mysql

Qual é a diferença de `SOME`, `IN` e `ANY` no MySql e quando devo usá-las?

Elas têm uma performance ruim se usadas muitas vezes no mesmo `SELECT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ANY` e `SOME` são sinônimos. Correlacionando de forma simples, ambas funcionam como um comando `EXISTS`.

Isso:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   x <= ANY
        (
        SELECT  y
        FROM    othertable
        )
```

É o mesmo que isso:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    othertable o
        WHERE   m.x <= o.y
        )
```

Com uma condição de igualdade em um campo Not-nullable, fica similar ao `IN`

Quanto a performace,esses comandos são considerados os mais lentos dentro do SQL, portanto evite utilizar muitos em uma query.

Comment: Excelente, +1. A documentação do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) dá bastante detalhes sobre como otimizar consultas com `IN`. Geralmente é possível extrair melhor performance com `EXISTS`, bem como facilitar a vida do otimizador quando você usa `NOT NULL` ou não precisa distinguir `NULL` de `FALSE`.

Answer (score 4):

Conforme [documentação oficial do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

### ANY

> "retorna `TRUE` se a comparação for verdadeira para *qualquer* dos valores na coluna que a subquery retorna." Por exemplo:
>
> ```
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 > ANY (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> ```
>
> Suponha que existe uma linha na tabela `t1`com o valor `10`. A expressão é verdadeira se a tabela `t2` contiver `(21, 14, 7)`pois `10 > 7`.

## IN

> Quando usado em uma subquery, a palavra `IN` é um apelido para `= ANY`. Assim, essas duas declarações são iguais:
>
> ```
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 = ANY (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN    (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> ```
>
> `IN` e `= ANY`não são sinonimos quando usados com uma lista de expressões. `IN` pode receber uma lista de expressões, mas `= ANY` não pode.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 2 IN (0,3,5,7);
>          -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 'wefwf' IN ('wee','wefwf','weg');
>          -> 1
> ```

## SOME

> A palavra `SOME` é um apelido para `ANY`. Assim, essas duas declarações são iguais:
>
> ```
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 <> ANY  (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 <> SOME (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> ```

---

## TL;DR

- `ANY / SOME` -> Expressões iguais. Para uma condição qualquer, retorna `TRUE` se existe qualquer valor na subquery que a satisfaça.
- `IN`-> Como `ANY`, porém limitado à expressões de igualdade (`IN` <-> `= ANY`). Além de uma subquery pode também receber uma lista de valores.

Comment: Amigo a sua resposta é mais completa, porém os exemplos não são tão intuitivos, ao menos para mim, mas mesmo assim +1, obrigado