# Qual a diferença entre LIKE, IN e BETWEEN no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com dúvida quanto a diferença e uso das tags `LIKE`, `IN` e `BETWEEN` no MySQL.
Quando devo usar as tags e exemplo?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cláusula / opearador **LIKE**

Utiliza-se a cláusula / operador `LIKE` quando se deseja fazer uma busca a um caracter, utilizando `coringa` ou seja `%`, se você quer efetuar uma varredura com caracteres que se iniciem com a palavra `A` o correto é fazer como irei mostrar abaixo. Primeiro repare na posicão do `coringa %` pois, faz diferença.

Aqui você irá buscar todos os registros que contém a letra  `A` na palavra. Na primeira alternativa somente com o coringa `%` e na segunda `%_caracter_%`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao LIKE "%A%" 
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao LIKE "%_A_%"
```

Aqui você irá buscar todos os registros que contém a letra  `A` no final da palavra.  Na primeira alternativa somente com o coringa `%` e na segunda `%_caracter`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao LIKE "%A"
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao LIKE "%_A"
```

Aqui você irá buscar todos os registros que contém a letra  `A` no início da palavra. Na primeira alternativa somente com o coringa `%` e na segunda `caracter_%`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao LIKE "A%"
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE descricao LIKE "A_%"
```

Agora vamos a cláusula **BETWEEN**

Você deve utilizar a cláusula `BETWEEN` quando deseja pegar apenas um intervalo do seu SELECT, ou seja, quer saber as vendas efetuadas entre o dia 10/11/2017 e 13/11/2017. Afinal a tradução de `BETWEEN` seria `Entre`. Irei indicar no select abaixo que quero buscar os registros entre o dia 10/11/2017 e 13/11/2017. Lembrando que para buscar um intervalo deve-se indicar somente 2 condições

```
Select  * FROM tabela WHERE vendas BETWEEN 10/11/2017 AND 13/11/2017
```

Agora vamos a cláusula **IN**

A cláusula `IN` é utilizada quando desejamos consultar uma tabela filtrando o valor de um de seus campos, a partir de uma lista de possibilidades. Ou seja, se deseja dar um `SELECT` em uma tabela onde possua N registros mas quer filtrá-los buscando apenas o que você acha necessário. Veja, que abaixo irei indicar que quero pegar os registros das pessoas que possuam o `ID` = 1,2,5,10 apenas.

```
SELECT * from pessoas WHERE id IN (1,2,5,10)
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que `_` também é um "coringa" do like [Curinga – corresponde a um caractere](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-match-one-character-transact-sql)

Comment: Olá @Everson, poderia editar a resposta incluindo esse detalhe, acho bem válido.

Comment: editei a resposta @RafaelWeber, veja se ficou bom e obteve clareza

Answer (score 5):

Exemplos na resposta do rray:

`LIKE`: é usado para fazer buscas parciais em campos do tipo texto (varhcar text etc) utilizando coringas % _.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo LIKE 'abc'

SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo LIKE '%abc%'
```

`IN`: Faz a comparação de um valor contra um conjunto fixo ou até mesmo com uma subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo IN ('abc','def')

SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo IN (10,20,30)

SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo IN (SELECT campo FROM tabela
    WHERE campo LIKE '%abc%')
```

`BETWEEN`: Compara um valor entre um intervalo de exatamente dois valores.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/10/2017'

SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 3):

- `LIKE`: é usado para fazer buscas parciais em campos do tipo texto (varhcar text etc) utilizando coringas `%` e `_`.
- `IN`: Faz a comparação de um valor contra um conjunto fixo ou até mesmo com uma subquery.
- `BETWEEN`: Compara um valor entre um intervalo de exatamente dois valores.

**Relacionadas:**

[Qual a diferença de SOME, IN e ANY?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58870/91)

[Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62925/91)

[Qual real diferença entre o operador '=' e LIKE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212220/91)

Answer (score 3):

**Between:**

[Definição](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql), utilizada para retornar registros baseados em uma faixa de valores. 
Proprício para campos do tipo numérico ou data, ex.:

`SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE Admissao BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-10-01'`

[SQLFiddle - Veja o exemplo funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9535/1)

**IN** e **Not IN:**

[Definição](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql), Utilizado para retornar registros cujos valores atendem ou não atendam a uma determinada lista.

```
SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE Admissao IN ('2017-11-12', '2017-09-12')

SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE Admissao NOT IN ('2017-11-12', '2017-09-12')
```

[SQLFiddle - Veja o exemplo com IN funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9535/2)   |  [SQLFiddle - exemplo com NOT IN funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9535/3)

**Like** e **Not Like:**

[Definição](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), utilizado para retornar registros que contenham ou não a cadeia de caracteres informada. Utiliza o `%` para controlar a forma de pesquisa.
Podendo variar sua busca em 3 formas:

[SQLFiddle - Valores iniciados com determinado conjunto de caracteres.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9535/5)

```
SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE Pessoa like 'Cai%'
```

[SQLFiddle - Valores que terminam com determinado conjunto de caracteres.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9535/7)

```
SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE Pessoa like '%los'
```

[SQLFiddle - Valores que contenham um determinado conjunto de caracteres.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb9535/8)

```
SELECT * FROM Funcionario WHERE Pessoa like '%ai%'
```