# Como realizar um select por múltiplas fk?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a um (ou mais) *select*.
Tenho o seguinte banco criado e preciso fazer uma busca de determinada receita com base em um (ou mais, e ai que está o problema) ingredientes.

Como consigo fazer para que retorne a receita que contém, *obrigatoriamente*, todos os ingredientes selecionados?

[image: Diagrama do banco de dados]

**OBS**: Um amigo me sugeriu *NoSQL* para esse tipo de estrutura, acham mais viável? Não entendo nada de *NoSQL*, mas como é um projeto de aprendizado a opção não está descartada.

Comment: Você quer a resposta em MySql, ou uma solução?

Comment: Basicamente você precisa fazer um `join` entre as tabelas filtrando em *ingredientes_receitas* os ingredientes e a quantidade para garantir que todos estão inclusos

Comment: @Sveen na verdade estou aceitando ambas. Se for a solução, só preciso entender corretamente para que eu possa implementar no My.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exibir **SOMENTE AS RECEITAS** que tenham **TODOS** os ingredientes, seria dessas formas:

Forma simplificada (creio eu, mais fácil):

```
SELECT re.cod_receita, COUNT(ig.cod_ingrediente)
FROM receitas re
LEFT JOIN ingredientes_receitas ir ON ir.cod_receita = re.cod_receita
LEFT JOIN ingredientes ig ON ig.cod_ingrediente = ir.cod_ingrediente
WHERE ig.cod_ingrediente IN (1,6)
GROUP BY re.cod_receita
HAVING COUNT(ig.cod_ingrediente) = 2
```

Você irá passar os ingredientes em:

`WHERE ig.cod_ingrediente IN (1,6)`

E a quantidade total de ingredientes (neste caso acima, são 2) em:

`HAVING COUNT(ig.cod_ingrediente) = 2`

O `HAVING COUNT` é necessário, pois nesta parte `WHERE ig.cod_ingrediente IN (1,6)`, você está selecionando **QUALQUER RECEITA** que tenha ao menos **UM DOS** ingredientes contidos em `(1,6)`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32156d/45)

---

Com sub-querys:

```
SELECT * 
FROM receitas
WHERE cod_receita IN
(
SELECT re.cod_receita
FROM receitas re
LEFT JOIN ingredientes_receitas ir ON ir.cod_receita = re.cod_receita
LEFT JOIN ingredientes ig ON ig.cod_ingrediente = ir.cod_ingrediente
WHERE ig.cod_ingrediente = 1
)
AND cod_receita IN
(
SELECT re.cod_receita
FROM receitas re
LEFT JOIN ingredientes_receitas ir ON ir.cod_receita = re.cod_receita
LEFT JOIN ingredientes ig ON ig.cod_ingrediente = ir.cod_ingrediente
WHERE ig.cod_ingrediente = 6
)
```

Você teria que filtrar receitas por ingredientes, e depois ver qual delas está em todos os selects.
Por hora, terá que fazer loop por ingrediente, e adicionar na verificação do select das receitas.
Na correria lembrei dessas formas... posteriormente verei se tem formas mais simples, pensando em gerar no PHP.

---

Links extras para `JOINS`:

[Diferença entre INNER JOIN, JOIN e WHERE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247921/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-join-e-where/247942#247942)

[Qual a diferença entre LIKE, IN e BETWEEN no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254946/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-like-in-e-between-no-mysql/254951#254951)

Comment: Poxa, é o mesmo caso que eu citei na [resposta do Gabriel Carvalho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286013/como-realizar-um-select-por-m%C3%BAltiplas-fk/287227#comment584972_287210) =/

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha visto Marcos... faz um favor, gera um SQLFiddle que eu dou uma olhada ! sqlfiddle.com ... caso não saiba, é só colocar o script de criação da estrutura do seu bd, e de inserts para o exemplo.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Pronto, coloquei no fiddle, deixei alguns dados de amostra e inseri sua query com a explicação. Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32156d/5/0

Comment: @MarcosTesolin eu fiz correndo uma forma que sei que dá certo... mas quando der, eu vejo se tem uma forma mais simples para a sua estrutura do BD.

Comment: Bacana, a primeira forma (com `HAVING` e `COUNT`) serviu muito bem a minha necessidade, além de ser simples e fácil de entender/implementar/modificar. Muito obrigado =D

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a relação de tabelas

```
SELECT 
    ingredientes.*,
    receitas.* 
FROM 
   ingredientes 
INNER JOIN ingredientes_receitas ON (ingredientes.cod_ingrediente = ingredientes_receitas.cod_ingrediente)
INNER JOIN receitas ON (ingredientes_receitas.cod_receita = receitas.cod_receita)
WHERE ingredientes.cod_ingrediente IN ("codigo1","codigo2")
```

Comment: A questão no `JOIN`, nesse caso, é que ele vai retornar todas as receitas que tenham **quaisquer** ingredientes que estejam dentro do `IN`, certo? O que eu procurava era algo que retornasse **somente** as receitas que tenham ambos os ingredientes.

Comment: Realmente Gabriel, desta forma irá trazer todas as receitas que tiverem ao menos 1 item, e ele quer que traga somente as que tiverem todos os itens.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei conseguindo uma solução utilizando *subqueries*. Eu fiz algo como:

```
select * from receitas where cod_receita in 
  (select * from ingredientes_receitas ir where cod_ingrediente = "codigo1") 
  and cod_receita in (select * from ingredientes_receitas ir where cod_ingrediente = "codigo2")
```

Só não sei se essa é a solução correta/mais elegante, até porque eu teria que fazer várias *subqueries* conforme a quantidade de filtros aumenta.

Caso tenham uma solução melhor, dica ou correção estou aceitando =D

Comment: Sua opção foi igual o meu primeiro exemplo, mas para gerar é mais trabalhoso e demanda maior processamento, por exemplo, caso uma receita tiver 20 ingredientes. No meu segundo exemplo, fica bem mais simples.