# Como posso selecionar uma faixa de itens, depois de alguns valores utilizando operador IN da SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Por exemplo:
Quero buscar, 1,2,5,7,11 e logo depois o restante até 100, numa DQL SELECT. Ex.:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN (1,2,5,7,11 ... value100);
```

No caso minha duvida está em relação ao uso do operador **IN** Não seria o BETWEEN

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre LIKE, IN e BETWEEN no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254946/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-like-in-e-between-no-mysql)

Comment: Me expressei errado na dúvida. Já editei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que voce tenha uma tabela como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    value INTEGER
);
```

Contendo os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  1,   1 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  2,   2 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  3,   3 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  4,   4 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  5,   5 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  6,   6 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  7,   7 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  8,   8 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES (  9,   9 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 10,  10 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 11,  11 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 12,  50 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 13,  60 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 14,  80 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 15, 100 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 16, 120 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, value ) VALUES ( 17, 200 );
```

Você pode fazer algo como:

```
SELECT
    id,
    value
FROM
    tb_foobar
WHERE
    value IN ( 1, 2, 5, 7 ) OR
    value BETWEEN 11 AND 100;
```

Saída:

```
| id | value |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  5 |     5 |
|  7 |     7 |
| 11 |    11 |
| 12 |    50 |
| 13 |    60 |
| 14 |    80 |
| 15 |   100 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d602/1

Answer (score 3):

Nesse caso você tem que usar o `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value100;
```

Veja mais sobre o `BETWEEN` [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: Considerando que `value1` até `value100`  estão todos ordenados e que são inteiros,datas, ou strings

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta. Havia me expressado errado.